# Why I can't import java.util.function package in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

In Android Studio 2.0 Beta 7, I can see this class "Consumer" in java.util.function.Consumer.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wa9et.png)

But I can't import it in Android Studio,why?
I have done these methods in gradle as follows.I am sure I have using Java8,because I can use default keyword in interface and this is new feature in Java8.

Can anybody tell me the reason?
java.util.stream package also occurer this phenomenon.

in gradle:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The package `java.util.function` is now made available in the Android runtime environment, hence you can import it. To find out which classes / packages are available to you in Android Runtime, [look up the reference here](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html).

Comment: java.util.function is present at the link you provided.

Comment: @tomatoRadar it wasn't available when the answer was written. Updating it.

Answer (score 2):

Those are from JDK 8, and that is only available at the moment [as part of some alpha build tools and the N Developer Preview](http://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html).